# How to create multi tenant SaaS app permissions in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how to create different roles and permissions for a mult-tenant(enterprise app with multiple customers). For example, our app has customerA and customerB, and each customer has their own users (customerAUser1, customerAUser2 etc) and with different roles of their own like "Admins", "Managers", "associates", "contractors" etc. These roles are different for each customer. Their admins decide what roles they want to have.

So an Admin of say customerA registers and says their company name as "customerA".

The Admin then in the UI, creates a "manager" role and allows access "people" section in the setup (assume there are multiple tabs in the setup). And then creates, "contractor" to not have any access to anywhere in the "setup".

Then the admin imports all their users from an excel file.

The excel file will look something like this:

```
name, email, phone, role
john,jo@customerA.com,123456,manager
jane,jane@customerA.com,123456,contractor
```

Similarly, AdminB of customerB registers his company and creates his own set of rules.

Now, everytime, a user logs in, we need to ensure that the data doesn't leak b/w customerA and customerB. So every collection in the DB needs to have "customerId" or something. Further, we need to check if people have access to certain collection based on their "role".

What's the best way to approach this in firestore DB?

Comment: This is a great question. Before you go to far with this project. I would strongly encourage you to reach out to Firebase directly to get some feedback about multi-tenant apps using Firebase - it can do it, but there's a number of trade offs; even with Firestore; ask about creating independent rules, admins creating users etc. You may even want to head over to their google groups section to have a bit more of a discussion.

Comment: I tried contacting their support and they gave me a vague answer

Comment: Including @FrankvanPuffelen from Firebase. Hmm. They are pretty well on point for support. Being a Firebase fan, I found that in general, Firebase was not a solution for some multi-tenant apps - especially those where there were different rule sets (as you mention in your question), completely separate data sets, as well having an admin user concept that can create other user accounts Again, Firebase is awesome and with Firestore multi-tenant apps can be done but there are a number of tradeoffs to consider before going to far with it.

Answer (score 4):

If there is never a case when Customer A and Customer B have the same users, the best way to tackle this is with subcollections. For instance:

```
customers/{customer_id}/users/{user_id}
```

Then, when querying and performing actions, you can always anchor on this:

```
firebase.firestore()
        .collection('customers')
        .doc('customerA')
        .collection('users')
        .where('role','==','admin')
```

If you *do* need cross-tenant visibility, then the correct way would be to have a `customer_id` or `tenant_id` in the document itself.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about having `customer_id` for every document because the same user might at some point work for some other customer. How do you suppose the path would look for things like: chat-messages, user-presence, etc in this kind of app? Thanks again!

Comment: @RajaRao How did you then ended up with this solution? I am looking for solution to exactly same situation. I have fairly large Multi-Tenant based SaaS app.